# Laravel route after post in same page ""

Tags: laravel

We are using Laravel, we have a form post on the "/",

$router->get('/', 'AppController@show');

The form is a script that appear through a modal window, once we post the form it uses route:

$router->post('/', 'AppController@store');

and function

```
public function store()
{
    return view('app');

}
```

How we can stay on page without any return action after the post ?

With the current method it reloads the "/" page,

Are there a way to keep the "/" page as it is without reloading after the submit button?

Apologise for my english, i hope you understand our issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should make ajax call on form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make an ajax call to that resource. You can do with with plain javascript or you can use jQuery for this. $.post('/').

Dependant on your version, version 5.4 has a covenant axios.post method that you can use with Vue to send your ajax requests.

For a simple app jQuery may be the best simple option for you.